# Angularjs $http does not send data

Tags: angularjs, http

I am working on a form where users can update her profile data and change avatar. My client-side code looks like this:

```
$http({
    method : 'PUT',
    url:  '/api/users/'+ userId,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest: function(data){
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('avatar', data.avatar);
      fd.append('user', angular.toJson(data.user));
      return fd;
    },
    data : {user: $scope.userData, avatar: $scope.file}
  })
```

Where $scope.file is an image file and $scope.userData are other data.
I use a directive that binds a callback to 'change' action in input element.

```
  el.bind('change', function(event){
        var file = event.target.files[0];
         scope.$emit('fileselected', {file: file});
      });
```

In my controller:

```
  $scope.$on('filesselected', function (event, args) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.getFile(args.file);
      $scope.file = args.file;
    });
  });
```

Bottom line, no data are sent to the server. I use Express at the server-side and
the output of console.log(req.body) is {}

---

#### Solved

Ok, i've just figured it out. The problem was with Express body parser. I have to manually install a 'multiparty' parser. And it works now

Comment: 1st thing why are you using content-type as undefined and and why are you transforming tou data like data? 3rd wouldn'g be easy to use use $http.put??

Comment: well, since i am sending a file, according to: http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs
"Angular’s default Content-Type header for POST and PUT requests is application/json, so we want to change this, too. By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request"

Comment: you should create the FormData Object outside the tranformation function chances are by the time you hit that your file is no longer available as file but as blobl in which case you need yo do something else. probably like the blobl [art in https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData. If you want to use the approach in the link you posted, get closer to it, and remove the transform function, crete a directive and moe the formData out of the request.

Comment: It didn't help. I've figured out in case i remove avatar, data are send with no problems.

Comment: What didn't help? following the post or using blob? can you do console,log inside your transform and see what format of data does data.avatar has?

Comment: I've figured out the problem appeared since I didn't have a proper Express parser. I've installed it and everything works. Thanx for your help

Comment: so the data was being sent. next time use chrome tools or firebug to explore the requests, will save you time